# Url Rewrite in IIS in webconfig

Tags: url-rewriting

Can anybody please help me in url rewrite to be done as

http://www.example.com/Directory/categoryName/ProductId/locationId

should redirect to

http://www.example.com/NewDirectory/index.php?category=categoryName&product=ProductId&location=locationId

Answer (score 0):

You may need custom rewrite provider for url rewriter module. How to write custom providers are clearly mentioned in [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module) article.

You don't need contents of method Initialize and GetSettings. In ReWrite method you can do string manipulation to your URL. You can pass your url as {ReplaceProvider:{URL}} in to ReWrite method.

```
public static string Rewrite(string value)
    {
        var parameters = value.Split('/');
        string retUrl = string.Format("http://www.example.com/NewDirectory/index.php?category={0}&product={1}&location={2}", parameters[parameters.Length-3], parameters[parameters.Length-2], parameters[parameters.Length-1]);
        return retUrl;
    }
```